# Java Formatter double or float will not display correctly

Tags: java, console, double, output, formatter

I am having a problem with the java formatter for output.

```
public void computeAverage() {
    double computeAvg = ((score1 + score2 + score3)/3.00);
    this.scoreAvg  = computeAvg;
}

String leftAlignFormat = "| %-11s | %-10s | %-6s | %-2s | %-2s | %-2s | %-5.2f | %-5s |" + newLine;

    System.out.format("+-------------+------------+--------+----+----+----+-------+-------+" + this.newLine);
    System.out.printf("| FirstName   | LastName   |   ID   | S1 | S2 | S3 |  AVG  | Grade |" + this.newLine);
    System.out.format("+-------------+------------+--------+----+----+----+-------+-------+" + this.newLine);
    System.out.format(leftAlignFormat, names[0], names[1], this.StudentID, this.score1, this.score2, this.score3, this.scoreAvg, this.grade);
```

Now I have tried a variety of variable types and conversion types (in the leftAlignFormat). No matter what, I can't seem to get any decimal places into the actual output. Iv tested the computeAverage in a helloworld type and can clearly see it returning decimals.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question: you are only trying to get decimals to show for 'AVG' (%-5.2f)?  Are score1, score2, score3 not also doubles?

Comment: They are only int. Average is the only decimals I am trying to show. And yes '%-5.2f' is the corresponding format code I can't seem to get to pass the double correctly.

Comment: If score1,2,3 are int why not format as %-2d?

Comment: If I try it with (1,2,3) I get `2,00` for `scoreAvg`. Maybe you reduce your code to the critical data (scoreX) and specify the input and the expected output.

Comment: I get a decimal aswell for scoreAvg. Again I am using the correct variable types, completely. Only when going through the System.out.format is not displaying correctly. My %-5.2f statement seems to not want to work.  http://i.imgur.com/11kzl8Z.jpg

Comment: @EricSamuel well, there is a chance it could be because of number format specific to a region. could you try to change your code to use `%-5,2f` instead of the `%-5.2f`?

Comment: Well, that did not work either. There must be stray code somewhere or I'm incorrect in my IDE program. I have executed from windows cmd and their is no .00. But when I run inside Jcreator and it captures the console.. I see .00.... I don't get it. But Thank you everyone.